# python - OOB/Class

Tags: python, class

i recently learned about Classes and subclasses, Ive tried some code but keep getting the error

> AttributeError: type object 'Assassin' has no attribute 'weapon'

here the Code: 
I think theres might be a problem with the inheritance.

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,name,**kwargs):
        self.name=name
        self.hp=500
        self.speed=50
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)


class Warrior(Character):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.weapon="Sword"
        self.armor="Giant Skin"
        super().__init__(name,hp,**kwargs)
    def hp(self,new_hp):
        self.new_hp=hp+500
        if hp > 900:
            print("Youre very healty!")


class Spearman(Warrior,Character):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.weapon="Spear"
        self.armor="Heavy Armor"
        super().__init__(name,hp,**kwargs)
    def rage(self):
        if weapon == "Spear":
            print("YOU ARE IN RAGE!")


class Thief(Character):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.weapon="Dagger"
        self.armor="Clean Fit"
        super().__init__(name,hp,**kwargs)
    def Avoidance(self,speed):
        if speed > 80:
            print("Avoided from enemy!")
        else:
            print("not fast enough!")


class Assassin(Thief,Character):
   def __init__(self,weapon,armor,**kwargs):
       self.weapon="Slim Dag"
       self.armor="Cloak of mystery"    
       super().__init__(name,hp,**kwargs)


dani=Assassin
omer=Spearman
print(dani.weapon)
print(dani.armor)
print(dani.hp)
print(dani.speed)
dani.Avoidance(100)
```

Comment: You instantiate objects of a class with the syntax: `obj = className()`

Answer (score 0):

**1**. In python in order to create an instance of a class the syntax is the following:

```
dani = Assassin("mg7", "cloak")
```

(The class Assassin only defines the characteristics of an assassin and what it can do. Actually creating an assassin in called instantiation)

**2**. In the **init** method for Assassin you are setting self.weapon and self.armor to a specific value. Why then do you need to get the weapon and armor values if you don't use them ?

**3**. In the **init** method for the classes you are calling the super with **name** and **hp** variables which do not exist.

**4**. Maybe it's for a unique purpose but at least I see no reason for you to inherit both **Thief AND Character** when Thief itself is already a subclass of character.(same for Spearman and Character)

**5**. According to python convention, method names should start with a lowercase(def avoidance instead of Avoidance).

**6**. If Thief.avoidance does not use the **self** parameter, you should change it to be a static method, by writing `@staticmethod` right above its definition. (and remove the self from the method parameters).

**7**. In a couple of methods there you access the instance variables without using "self.", while this works in Java and C#, in java you **MUST** access the instance variables with the self parameter(which is a pointer to the instance).

Take a look here for more information:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: This answer is very incomplete as it addresses only one of the many issues with OP's code. The question is where to begin.

Comment: Yes I see that now